# Trying to create buttons in swift using a nested for loop, but keep getting the wrong count when I append them to my array which is empty

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, button

I am trying to create 27 buttons, then append them to my array of letterButtonsArray, which is empty at the start, but should contain 27 letters after I append them.  from there I want to set the title of each button which I know how to do.
However, I am having difficulties with the button creation part.  Every time I create the buttons and add them to my letterButtonsArray, I keep getting a count of 54, meaning it's adding each item twice and I have no idea why.  I have been stuck on this since yeserday.  Here's the code

```
let width = 80
let height = 60
    
for row in 0..<3{
    for col in 0..<9{
        let letterButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        letterButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
        letterButton.setTitle("A", for: .normal)
        let frame = CGRect(x: col*width, y: row*height, width: width, height: height)
        letterButton.frame = frame
        buttonView.addSubview(letterButton)
        letterButtonsArray.append(letterButton)
            
    }
}
```

I need the letterButtonsArray to contain 27 buttons, not 54.

Comment: Where have you written this code?

Comment: How is this code called?

Comment: This code is written in a function called loadView(), that loads before viewDidLoad().  This loadView() functions also contains two UIlabels(), one UItextField().

and it is called in viewDIdload() of course.

Comment: Regarding `loadView()` Apple says: ***You should never call this method directly***. This is most likely the reason of the confusion. Please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

Comment: That can't be the reason because I watched Paul Hudson from hackingwithswift do the same exact thing, and his worked while mine didn't.  I am still very confused as to why.

Comment: Please share the link where Paul does that. I'm pretty sure that moving the code from `loadView` to `viewDidLoad` will solve the issue.

Comment: here's the link, please start at 32minutes mark.  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhxhKpyyQzE

Comment: Paul does not call `loadView` in `viewDidLoad()` at all. There is a misunderstanding: `loadView` can be **overridden** and it's getting called by the framework. Remove the `loadView()` call in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thank you for your help.
I have been stuck on this since yesterday.
Thanks again.